# Suggestions for projects in mathematics of finance

Tags: numerical-methods, economics

I am looking for computational projects related to mathematics of finance suitable for a senior level independent study for a student who has seen the green light, (or the light of the green!). I had a brief encounter with [Black Scholes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes) formula some n years ago. But I am looking for a site that has a listing of several ideas. Similar questions have been posted on this site but the pickings are slim. I thought I try anyway.

Comment: Nassim Taleb has some pretty controversial ideas on mathematics of finance. It is not a site, but you may want to peruse through his two main books for some inspiration: Fooled by Randomness and The Black Swan.

Comment: Did you ever find what you were looking for?

Comment: @JoeJohnson126  No, the question  does not generate enough interest in this community.

Comment: Did you ever find your answer in another community?

Comment: No, not that I recall. However there is a "quantitative finance" stack exchange. My student ended up writing a thesis on simulation of planetary motion via RK methods.